# Nodemailer and nodemailer-express-handlebars and/or express-handlebars will not use template

Tags: nodemailer, express-handlebars

I would like to understand how to get nodemailer to work with nodemailer-express-handlebars and/or express-handlebars in order to use node to send an email with an html template.

File structure:

[image]

Dependencies: (Do I need both express-handlebars and nodemailer-express-handlebars?)

```
"express-handlebars": "^5.3.0",
"nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
"nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
```

Server.js

```
import expresshbs from "express-handlebars";

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine("handlebars", expresshbs({ defaultLayout: false }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

booking.controller.js

```
import hbs from "nodemailer-express-handlebars";
                
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "xxx",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: "xxx",
        pass: process.env.EMAILPASS,
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
       },
 });

transporter.use(
    "compile",
    hbs({
        viewEngine: "nodemailer-express-handlebars",
        viewPath: "emailTemplates/",
    })
);

const mailOptions = {
    from:
        "xxx",
    to: "xxx" // list of receivers
    subject: "subject",
    template: "newbooking",
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Message sent");
    }
});
```

In the root of the project I have a template main.handlebars however I would like to delete this and force the routine to use the newbooking.handlebars template in emailTemplates.

Current behaviour:

If I call the booking.controller.js then I receive an email but it uses the main.handlebars template.

If I rename newbooking.handlebars in any way (eg newbookingx.handlebars) I get the error can't find newbooking.handlebars.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../E-Server/emailTemplates/newbooking.handlebars'

So it is clearly looking for newbooking.handlebars but not using it, and it is using main.handlebars instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would start creating a folder called `emails` e.g. and in this folder you create a subfolder called `layouts`.
In the folder called `emails` you put all your handlebars emails. In the layouts folder, you put your email template newbooking.handlebars.

If you've done that, change the `transporter.use()` to the following code:

```js
    transporter.use(
        "compile",
        hbs({
              viewEngine: {
          extname: '.handlebars', // handlebars extension
          layoutsDir: 'emails/layouts/', // location of handlebars templates
          defaultLayout: 'newbooking', // name of main template
      },
      viewPath: 'emails',
      extName: '.handlebars',
      };
        })
    );
```

The following code defines that the layouts are located in the `emails/layouts/` folder and the name of the defaultLayout is `newbooking`. The viewPath defines that the emails are located in the `/emails` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need both express-handlebars and nodemailer-express-handlebars?

No, you just need nodemailer-express-handlebars which internally uses express-handlebars as [the official site](https://github.com/yads/nodemailer-express-handlebars#express-handlebars-plugin-for-nodemailer) states.
I noticed you have your `emailTemplates` folder at same level of the `app` folder. You have two options:

1. Move your `emailTemplates` into `app` folder and in there you just change this:

   ```
   transporter.use(
   "compile",
   hbs({
     viewEngine: {
       layoutsDir: "app/emailTemplates/", // location of handlebars templates
       defaultLayout: 'newbooking', //default layout. This is necessary if you don't want to use main.handlebars
     },
     viewPath: "app/emailTemplates/"
   })
   );
   ```
2. Don't move anything in your files and folders but changue this:

   ```
   transporter.use(
   "compile",
   hbs({
     viewEngine: {
       layoutsDir: "emailTemplates/", // location of handlebars templates
       defaultLayout: 'newbooking', //default layout. This is necessary if you don't want to use main.handlebars
     },
     viewPath: "emailTemplates/"
   })
   );
   ```

There are a few things to mention:

1. `extName` plugin option is not necessary because it defaults to .handlebars extension.
2. You need to explicity define `defaultLayout` and `layoutsDir` in `viewEngine` plugin option even if you define them on your `template` inside mailOptions and `viewPath` plugin option.

Hope it helps.